# Connection string property is lost in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-7.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 7 Web API. It seems to have trouble with `ConnectionString` when it is specified in either `appsettings.Development.json` or in `User Secrets`.

`Program.cs`

```
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddDbContext<WorldCitiesContext>(optionsBuilder =>
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

...
var connectionString = app.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
Console.WriteLine(connectionString);
```

And here is controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CountriesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly WorldCitiesContext _context;

    public CountriesController(WorldCitiesContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Country>>> GetCountries() =>
    await _context.Countries.ToListAsync();
}
```

and here is connection string:

```
Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=WorldCitiesGolden;Integrated Security=true
```

I get this error:

> Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=WorldCitiesGolden;Integrated Security=true
> An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'WorldModel.WorldCitiesContext'.
> System.InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
>
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand()
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.PermissionDemand(DbConnection outerConnection)
> at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
> at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.InternalOpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

As you can see, the value is assigned correctly; however, it is somehow lost in Controller. Previously, in ASP.NET Core 6 and before, `Configuration` was initiated explicitly, in

```
new ConfigurationBuilder()
       .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment}.json")
       .AddUserSecrets()
```

but now it is [supposed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=windows) to happen *automagically*.

What can be the cause of the error?

Comment: Could you show us, how you've configured your DbContext and how you are using / initializing it in your controller?

Comment: It doesn't have to  call .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment}.json") or  .AddUserSecrets() now, have you checked  if you could get the connect string with var connectionString = app.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with the codes you provided,could you show how you configured in appsettings.development.json  and secret,json  , if you overrided the OnConfiguring method in your dbcontext?

Comment: On what environment are you experiencing the issues. Note that both `appsettings.Development.json` and User Secrets are only for development. Can you please post a full [mre] somewhere?

Comment: Also JIC what is the value of `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable?

Comment: @GuruStron - yes, it is Development environment; it is run from Visual Studio, and `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` is set to Development. I log the value and it comes correctly; but it is lost in Controller. I think the code above *is* minimal reproducible example - but I also put it into github: https://github.com/virshu/sp23-comp584-WorldCitiesServer

Comment: @Felix was not able to repro. Your github sample works fine and returns `Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=WorldCitiesGolden;Integrated Security=true` to me for injected context connection string.

Comment: @Felix also note that you have "Copy Always" set for `appsettings.json` in the `WorldModel` project so it potentially can override the `appsettings.json` file from the runnable project.

Comment: @GuruStron - I checked runtime directory `bin\Debug\net7.0\ ` and both appsettings files are there as expected. Again - I see that Program.cs reads the configuration properly; I print it out. The question is, why DbContext loses it by the time it gets to controller

Comment: @Felix 1) override does not mean that the file will disappear =) 2) _"why DbContext loses it by the time it gets to controller"_ - this does not reproduce with fresh checkout of provided repo - `var connectionString = _context.Database.GetConnectionString();` returns the value from the config in the controller.

Comment: @Felix P.S. - `_context.Countries == null` - is pointless check and can be safely removed (at least if you use idiomatic approach of working with EF).

Comment: @GuruStron - yes, I checked out what I committed, into a new project - and it is working. Mystery

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using net core and appsettings.json your connection string should have double \ and  this syntax

```
"Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=...";
```

Comment: you are correct; appsettings.json has double backslash (I think somebody edited my post). As I said, the value works from appsettings, but doesn't work in appsettings.Development or from user secrets. But it looks like the same code checked out from repo and built as new project works now. So, this will remain mystery

Answer (score -1):

add

```json
 "Settings": {
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "SqlServer": "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Test;User ID=sa;Password=123456;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;TrustServerCertificate=True;Connection Timeout = 60"
    }} ,
```

in appsettig.json

then add

```
public class Settings
{
    public string SqlServer { get; set; }
}
```

after that in program.cs add

```
Settings settings = config.GetRequiredSection("Settings").Get<Settings>();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
        {
            options
                .UseSqlServer(settings.SqlServer);
        });
```

Comment: thanks @sedaghat. Can you point to any source for such unconventional approach?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings

Comment: Why do you think this will have any effect?